# wordpress plugin query is not setting properly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a plugin for routing the wordpress pages. So in that i am checking for variable is_404. but which is not set in that plugin. but it is set after words. means ultimately it is calling 404 page only. and if i am checking that variable in 404 page then its value is 1. so can any body tell me what should i do so that I can get that variable's value properly in my plugin? My code is as follows.

```
function site_router() {
global $route,$wp_query,$window_title;
$bits =explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if ( $wp_query->is_404 ) {
    die("test..");
}
}
add_action( 'send_headers', 'site_router');
```

Comment: That property is set after a specific point in time only. Your plugin can only usefully access it after it has been set. You need to reverse-engineer wordpress and debug the request to find out when this is the case. It's pretty early, but not when your plugin is loaded. That's too early. See as well the [`is_404`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp', 'site_router');
```

with the help of above line that variable is being set.